# Which is adapter connected? netsh

Tags: adapter, netsh

I with the command

netsh int sho int

I can see the adapters on the pc

is there a way to know which adapter is connected?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command on CMD to know the current adapter you are connected currently.

`netsh interface show interface`

Comment: I want to know the ethernet in use

Comment: type ipconfig in cmd prompt and there you can see the ethernet in use.